# c# method inside of a class that returns values

Tags: c#

currently i have a class like this;

```
public static class drug
{
    public const double[] coc = new double[] { 156, 4, 8, 164 };
    public const double[] mar = new double[] { 234, 64, 34, 342 };

}
```

the way i reference it is like this:

```
double one = drug.coc[0];
```

however i would like to reference it like this

```
double one = drug.coc.var1
```

how can i change my class to support this?

Comment: do you mean drug.coc[var1] == drug.coc.var1 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest it in the same fashion... however, you'd obviously lose any array functionality.

```
public static class drug
{
    public static class coc
    {
        public const double var1 = 156;
        public const double var2 = 4;
        public const double var3 = 8;
        public const double var4 = 164;
    }
    public static class mar
    {
        public const double var1 = 234;
        public const double var2 = 64;
        public const double var3 = 34;
        public const double var4 = 342;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Coc` class with `var1`, `var2` etc and use that instead of the `double[]`.

Note: You should be using properties instead of exposing fields in this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .Net 4, and don't mind declaring your "drug" class as a dynamic, you can inherit from "DynamicObject" and overload the TryGetMember method to parse the incoming method name into a valid index into your array.

REAAAAALLY quick and dirty, and not exactly what you wanted, and I don't have time to tweak it, but it works.

```
void Main()
{
    dynamic d = new drug();

    double v1 = d.mar0; //234
    double v2 = d.mar1; //64
    double v3 = d.mar2; //34 
    double v4 = d.mar3; //342
}

public class drug : DynamicObject
{
    private double[] coc = new double[] { 156, 4, 8, 164 };
    private double[] mar = new double[] { 234, 64, 34, 342 };

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        string name = binder.Name.ToLower();
        if(name.StartsWith("coc"))
        {
            result = coc[int.Parse(name.Replace("coc",""))];
            return true;
        }
        if(name.StartsWith("mar"))
        {
            result = mar[int.Parse(name.Replace("mar",""))];
            return true;
        }
        result = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To be able to reference your values via a variable you would have to refactor your class so that the **cac** variable is another class

```
public class ValueCollection
{
   public ValueCollection(double var1, double var2, double var3, double var4)
   {
      Var1 = var1;
      Var2 = var2;
      Var3 = var3;
      Var4 = var4;
   }

   public double Var1 { get; private set; }
   public double Var2 { get; private set; }
   public double Var3 { get; private set; }
   public double Var3 { get; private set; }
}
```

Then you would update your original class:

```
public static class drug
{
    public ValueCollection coc = new ValueCollection(156,4,8,164);
    public ValueCollection mar = new ValueCollection(234,64,34,342);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it an enum: `public enum { var1=156, var2=4, var3=8 var4=164}`. I might be off on the syntax a bit, but it should be a start.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138362.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Being able to do what you want would require that you know, beforehand, exactly how many doubles there would be in your coc collection (array, IEnumerable, whatever).  Presuming you do know that, you'll still need a property, such that coc would become a class itself:

```
public class DrugInfo
 {
    public double var1 {get;set;}
    public double var2 {get;set;}
    public double var3 {get;set;}
    public double var4 {get;set;}
 }
```

Then, your new code would look like this:

```
DrugInfo coc = new DrugInfo() { 156, 4, 8, 164 };
DrugInfo mar = new DrugInfo() { 234, 64, 34, 342 };
```

Which you could then access like: `drug.coc.var1` or `drug.mar.var1`.

Answer (score 0):

I may be off on what you are asking but you could use a Dictionary like so

```
public Dictionary<string, double> coc = new Dictionary<string, double>()
        {
        {"var1", 156}, {"var2", 4}, {"var3", 8}
        };
```

And the retrieve the values like so

```
double d = drug.coc["var1"]
```